# How can I integrate open source Apis on my website hosted by Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I'm making a cloud system and I want to integrate some open source APIs like Writer,Image Viewer etc..
I'm using **GWT** framework and **Google App Engine** as a host server 
I know that my Apis must be in Python or Java which Google app Engine platform support so I searched for one of them and found API called
**Zoho Writer**

Answer (score 0):

If what you're looking for is access to Google's public APIs, and you're using Eclipse with Google Plugin for Eclipse, then you have a button that brings up a list of all Google APIs that have GWT interfaces, and allows you to install the client library for each.

See here: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/googleapis

Comment: Firstly Thanks very much but that wasn't actually what I need I know that you can easily integrate any Google App but I'm asking for APPs not from Google like Zoho Writer (You can't find all you need in Google Apps)

Comment: You can take a look at how I implemented a wrapper for YouTube's public API in this project: https://github.com/popsimple/popsimple/blob/master/gwt-youtube/src/com/project/gwtyoutube/client/YouTubeSearchRequest.java